# Запуск исполняемого файла на сервере

Tags: php

Как запустить скомпилированный файл `.exe` или какой другой, и самое главное как передать ему параметры из `$_GET` и вывести результат выполнения на страницу? Запуск можно сделать командой `exec`, запускал через неё оконные приложения (exe) из Open Server. А вот как результат вывести на страницу не знаю.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону CGI

Comment: Ведь речь же идет о запуске чего-то из PHP? Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: нужно exe запустить из php

Comment: нужно передать exe два числа из гет запроса, и вывести результат их сложения

Comment: обновил свой ответ для работы с целыми числами из $_GET

Comment: спасибо, попробую на выходных

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о запуске какой-то консольной утилиты из PHP, то можно сделать, например, так:

```
$command = sprintf(
    'sum.exe %d %d',
    intval($_GET['a']),
    intval($_GET['b'])
);

$output = array();
exec($command, $output);
echo(implode("\n", $output));
```

Подробнее здесь: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php

UPD:

Вообще, вызов консольных команд из PHP является плохой практикой с точки зрения безопасности. По этому, по возможности, таких вещей нужно избегать.

Answer (score 0):

1. если запуск производится на сервере то малая вероятность того что это окажется удобной ля Вас `ОС`. **39%** если верить статистики *(понятно что статистика не является полной и достоверной, но другой у меня нет)*, но я думаю данные значительно завышены. А для запуска exe приложения в иной ОС, Вам потребуется до устанавливать специализированный софт и права на выполнение)

> [пруф](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133783/)

2. единственной возможным способом передачи параметров при запуске приложения следующие способы:

   - передача параметров по ссылке (ярлык и запуск с параметрами в терминале)

следовательно чтобы получить `$_GET` параметре и передать его в приложение Вам понадобится приложение прослойка. Которая и возьмет на себя эти обязанности

3. Использование функции `exec` крайне не рекомендуется

> [пруф2](http://www.php.su/security/)